# mfc42.dll segfault with ktrans

Tags: segmentation-fault, karel

I'm not sure if this problem is oddball or trivial.

The background is the following: We have a FANUC robot in our lab, that can be interfaced via their proprietary KAREL language (I'm just realizing that my tag is probably misleading). A technician provided me with the compiler - ktrans.exe - that "runs on his machine". On my machine, however, it fails silently. Both are Windows 10 Professional.

From what I can see with gdb in Powershell (Win10 and Win8) and running it under wine (Ubuntu16 and Sabayon Linux), is that there is a segfault that seems to be related to mfc42.dll.

Trace from Powershell gdb: `gdb ktrans.exe` https://pastebin.com/qeBBTKGu
Trace from wine: `wine ktrans.exe` https://pastebin.com/tnCj9DrB

There is no difference in errors if I run this in 32 bit or 64 bit.

We will get FANUC's offline programming suite in a while, which should resolve the problem. But I'd like to have this one capability earlier and I'm also curious about what's going on.

Does anyone have a hint on why this is may be happening? Or what could I look into to debug this further? I have no access to the ktrans sources.

Best,

Niki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That technician that provided ktrans gave you an incomplete piece of software.
ktrans is part of some FANUC softwares (Roboguide and OLPCPro) which create a virtual controller **prior** to call ktrans, because the target robot controller version must be known.

Being here: FANUC does not support its software to run on Linux or virtual machines.

Comment: wow. i'm actually surprised someone answered this :)... 
as the problem is largely resolved (i got roboguide), some additional info: 
i seem to have gotten an awkward version. ktrans **is** supposed to run standalone as a commandline tool. the karel tutorial presentation explicitly mentions this. the virtual controller is not required. 
for crossplatform stuff: yes, obviously fanuc does not support linux and roboguide will not run on virtual machines at all. **however**, maketp (translates ls sources to tp programs) runs just fine on linux with wine. i haven't tried ktrans yet.

Comment: Yes, ktrans is supposed to run as standalone, but it's quite tricky and some other components are required, the exe file, as far as I remember, it not enough.